# Structures of Thiosulfate, Dithionate & Tetrathionate Ions

Tags: ions

I am trying to find the structures of thiosulfate, Dithionate & Tetrathionate Ions but I am not getting an exact answer. Please help.

Comment: Can you expand on your question?  Where are you getting stuck?  What have you figured out so far?  As it is, this is likely to get closed because it is a homework question that does not show your input or ask about a specific concept.

Comment: Have you tried a common web-based search engine? [Thiosulfate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thiosulfate) [Dithionite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dithionite) [Tetrathionate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrathionate)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it can be easily found using Google and/or Wikipedia.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go...

[Thiosulfate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thiosulfate) $\ce{[S2O3]^{-2}}$

[image]

There ia a negative charge on the apical sulfur and another negative charge distributed across the 3 oxygens by resonance

[Dithionate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dithionate) $\ce{[S2O6]^{-2}}$

[image]

There is one negative charge distributed by resonance over each group of 3 oxygens.

[Dithionite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dithionite) $\ce{[S2O4]^{-2}}$

[image]

There is one negative charge distributed by resonance over each group of 2 oxygens.

[Tetrathionate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrathionate) $\ce{[S4O6]^{-2}}$

[image]

There is one negative charge distributed by resonance over each group of 3 oxygens.

Comment: You have written "Dithionate", but the formula and molecular structure shown are those of dithionite.

Comment: @JannisAndreska  Thanks for catching that, I'll edit the answer.