Structure of H2S2O3
I'm learning how to draw the structures of compounds now, and I came across the compound H2S2O3. I drew it in a way similar to how I had drawn compounds like H2S2O8, trying to have a symmetry between the bondings of the two Sulphur atoms. This was my structure:

However, this is the actual structure:

Why is the structure I drew wrong? What is the reason for the increased stability of the second model as compared to the first?

The intermediate step between questioning the formula and asking for reasons would be learning the basics of sulphur chemistry.

@OscarLanzi The acid is known and preparations are given on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thiosulfuric_acid . But it doesn't have either of the above structures.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/18762/structures-of-thiosulfate-dithionate-tetrathionate-ions https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/55112/what-is-the-correct-structure-of-sodium-thiosulfate

Actually it's S that should be protonated, so even your "good" structure isn't the most important Oxidation state of the sulfur atoms in the thiosulfate Ion. Even if it was there should be dative bonds instead of double.

@Mithoron, I've edited the question to include the structure as was concluded by the article cited in the answer to the question that you have provided. However, why is it that the structure I had drawn is wrong? Without any information given that it is an acid, etc, why isn't this structure valid? What is the reason behind its lower stability where both the Sulphur atoms have similar bondings?

Your edit of the question now has a structure for the ion (without hydrogens), while the original question was about the acid (with hydrogens). They are different things. Which are you asking about? One of the big questions in this system is whether one of the hydrogens bonds to sulphur, rather than oxygen, so if you are not interested in the acid we need to know.

@IanBush sorry about that. I've added the hydrogens now.

You didn't add them like I said. BTW why is your first idea bad? Well, I wouldn't even think of such weird isomer. Maybe some guys made it in argon matrix. What made you think there could be O=S-H group in there?

@Mithoron I'm afraid I'm not able to understand your concerns. Could you please explain what you mean?

Well, wait for an answer. You picked a compound which is particularly tricky and bit more than you can chew.


i hope you know about VSEPR theory which causes a bent shape in the S-H bond
the Middle Sulphur atom is sp3 hybridised so its tetrahedral

This is technically correct, but you should reference the source, including your own work if that's what you did.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/76740/17368
